# boost deflate and unsigned char ptr

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, deflate

I have pointer to unsigned char array and length of data
For example:

```
int length = 10;  
unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[length];  
std::fill(data, data + length - 1, 0x03);
```

I need to deflate data, and get result in unsigned char array
I have found many examples of using boost zlib (ex. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880805/1779649), but all of them are using strings and many data copying.
How can i deflate unsigned char array and get result in other unsigned char array with as few data copying as possible?